# Sql query with multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I'm not very used to SQL queries, but I have to do this query that involves a lot of tables. Here they are:

(Note: `id` is always the `PRIMARY KEY`.)

```
A(id, name)
B(id, title, a_id, FOREIGN KEY(a_id) REFERENCES A(id))
C(id, d_id, b_id, FOREIGN KEY (d_id) REFERENCES D(id), FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (b_id) REFERENCES B(id))
D(id, content)
E(id d_id, a_id, c_id, FOREIGN KEY (d_id) REFERENCES D(id), FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A(id),  FOREIGN KEY (C_id) REFERENCES c(id))
```

I need to retrive all the rows from table `E`.

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT *
FROM E
LEFT JOIN D ON E.d_id = D.id
LEFT JOIN A ON E.a_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN B LEFT JOIN A ON B.a_id = B.id
ON C.b_id = B.id
LEFT JOIN D ON C.d_id = D.id
ON E.c_id = C.id
```

But it gives me a runtime error:

> Ambiguous column name "ID";

Can anybody give me a hint to solve this problem?

Comment: I would advise you never to use *, but explicitly specify the individual columns. That way in case the table design changes, your query will not suddenly include unexpected/unnecessary columns. If you need only the values from E, you could simply issue a `SELECT ID, D_ID, A_ID, C_ID FROM E`. It doesn't look as if the other tables include any useful or descriptive information about the other IDs. In case they do, you could do soemthing like `SELECT E.ID, D.name FROM E JOIN D ON e.D_ID = D.ID`.

Comment: If you want to learn the fundamentals of sql, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  In 11 minutes, you might be answering questions instead of asking them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with this statement

`LEFT JOIN B LEFT JOIN A ON B.a_id = B.id` ? There is no condition specified for the first `left join`?

Also, you are comparing B.a_id to B.id which is just comparing two columns in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM E
LEFT JOIN D ON E.d_id = D.id
LEFT JOIN A ON E.a_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = B.a_id
LEFT JOIN C ON C.b_id = B.id AND c.d_id = d.Id
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you gave me the right hint I was looking for.Your solution doesn't work, but with a little work now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename id in other tables, or don't view id.

In SQL Server:

Select A.id AS id_A, B.id AS id_B...